# Cannot run this program from cmd with classpath option

Tags: java, cmd, classpath

this is a beginner question. I am having a problem running my java program from command line. I am using Windows10.
The problem is the following. I have a folder named "folder1", which is located o the dekstop of my computer. So the full path would be 
C:\Users\Ioanna\Desktop\folder1
Inside that folder I have created a second folder which I named folder2. so the path to this would be
C:\Users\Ioanna\Desktop\folder1\folder2

Inside folder2 I have a java file named example.java
I want to compile it and run this file with setting the -classpath option through cmd. I dont want to set the path or to add the folder to tha path from environment variables.

I am trying

```
C:\Users\Ioanna\javac -cp C:\Users\Ioanna\Desktop\folder1\folder2 example.java
```

but it says file not found.
I tried several other alternatives, but I can't seem to find how to compile successfully the program.

Comment: Are you in C:\Users\Ioanna\Desktop\folder1\folder2 ? What does javac print exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code compilation (to bytecode) and code execution are two separate steps, in Java.

First, compile your `.java` to obtain the corresponding `.class` file *(I'm assuming your folder paths are right)*:

```
C:\Users\Ioanna\javac C:\Users\Ioanna\Desktop\folder1\folder2\example.java
```

This will give you `example.class` in that same folder.
Next, run that class (provided it has a `main()` method):

```
C:\Users\Ioanna\java -cp C:\Users\Ioanna\Desktop\folder1\folder2 example
```

Comment: No. java doesn't expects a path to a .class file. It expects a fully qualified class name, and looks for the corresponding .class file in the classpath.

Comment: @JBNizet So the instructions in my example won't work?

Comment: The first one will. The second won't. Assuming the example class is in the default package (which is a bad practice), it would have to be `java -cp C:\Users\Ioanna\Desktop\folder1\folder2 example`.

Comment: @JBNizet Yep, fixed. Too much used to IDE's I guess.

Answer (score 1):

java expects the path of the file(s) to compile. And example.java is not in the current folder (C:\Users\Ioanna).

Use

```
javac Desktop\folder1\folder2\example.java
```

Comment: thanks that worked !! It compiled ! and what do I user to run the example.class?